# How to add a column to mnesia table

Tags: erlang, mnesia, erl

I am trying to add new column to an existing mnesia table. For that, I use following code.

```
test()->

Transformer =
  fun(X)->
      #users{name = X#user.name,
           age = X#user.age,
           email = X#user.email,
          year = 1990}
end,
{atomic, ok} = mnesia:transform_table(user, Transformer,record_info(fields, users),users).
```

Two records I have

```
-record(user,{name,age,email}).
-record(users,{name,age,email,year}).
```

My problem is when I get values from my `user` table it comes as

`{atomic,[{users,sachith,28,sachith@so,1990}]}`

Why do I get `users` record name when I retrieve data from `user` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name and the record name are not necessarily the same.  You started out with a table called `user` holding `user` records, and then you transformed all the `user` records into `users` records.  So when you read from the table, it will return `users` records, since that's what the table now contains.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [internal representation of record](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#internal-representation-of-records),

`-record(Name, {Field1,...,FieldN}).` is represented by `{Name,Value1,...,ValueN}`.

So, basically you are converting `{user,name,age,email}` to `{users,name,age,email,year}` in your table.

But there is better approach for such migration which will come in handy as you update your records later,

Looking at [this](https://github.com/Cuick/qise/blob/2d43b1aba070b202c614313e00d7671de4ce8292/src/modules/db/data_change.erl) production codebase a better snippet for the `transformer` function,

```erlang
%%-record(user,{name,age,email}). // old
%%-record(user,{name,age,email,year}).  // new

Transformer =
  fun(X)->
      #user{name = element(2,X),
           age = element(3,X),
           email = element(4,X),
          year = 1990}
end,
```